# Remove blocking call in Play

Tags: scala, playframework

I am trying to get the time spend for each request to send it to a remote system in my Play application.

The case class `TimeAction` which works well with asynchronous action doesn't work with synchronous action

```
//Helper
case class TimeAction(label: String] = Map()) = {
  def logging[A](action: Action[A])(implicit ec: ExecutionContext) = 
    Action.async(action.parser) { request =>
      MetricLogger.timeFuture(s"controllers.action.$label") {
        action(request)
    }
  }
}

//controller
def test =
  TimeAction("toto.test.sync").logging {
    Action { _ =>
      Thread.sleep(4000)
      Ok
    }
  }
// expected output 4003 milliseconds but got 3 milliseconds

def testAsync =
  TimeAction("toto.test.async").logging {
    Action.async { _ =>
      Future {
        Thread.sleep(4000)
        Ok
      }
    }
  }
// go 4003 milliseconds as expected

//calculate time elapsed during a future
def timeImpl[T](f: Future[T], 
                onError: (Duration, Throwable) => Unit, 
                onSuccess: (Duration, T) => Unit)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[T] = {
    val start = System.nanoTime
    f.onComplete {
      case Success(d) => onSuccess(calculateTimeDiff(start, System.nanoTime()), d)
      case Failure(e) => onError(calculateTimeDiff(start, System.nanoTime()), e)
    }
    f
}
```

I suppose the action is executed before it got to my `TimeAction` and is only wrapped in a instant `Future`. Do you know where ? What am I missing ?

I am using Play 2.3